# MySQL won't start: "Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Operation not permitted"

Tags: mysql, centos6, rhel6

Running a minimal Centos 6.0 build as a vagrant box, with SELINUX=permissive.  Right off the bat, performing a "yum install mysql-server" and then "service mysqld start" it fails.

Inside /var/log/mysql.log we have the following--

```
130815 10:47:32 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
130815 10:47:32 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
130815 10:47:32  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
130815 10:47:32  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130815 10:47:32  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
130815 10:47:32 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Operation not permitted
130815 10:47:32 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock ?
130815 10:47:32 [ERROR] Aborting

130815 10:47:32  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130815 10:47:38  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 44233
130815 10:47:38 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

130815 10:47:38 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

I've googled and googled on this and am quite stuck.  Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: ps -waux |grep -i 'mysqld' - is it running already?

Comment: Please post your my.conf

Comment: we need to see your my.conf,  almost sounds like mysql user can't create files to expected locations, i.e. socket file

Answer (score 1):

This was happening due to a misconfiguration in the installed /etc/my.cnf.  It was placing the socket and pid files inside /var/lib/mysql when the pid needed to be in /var/run/mysqld and the socket in /

Comment: Please accept your own answer if this fixed it and (if possible) expand it a little with config snippets to show what you changed. This way the answer is useful for future users.

Answer (score 0):

You may check your mysql server status using

> chkconfig mysqld

start your mysql server using root user.